# $132$ chairs and $24$ people

Tags: elementary-number-theory

There are $132$ chairs and $24$ people. The number of chairs may vary but will always be $> 24$. The chairs are numbered $(1, 2, 3, \dots, 132)$.

I want to sit all $24$ people leaving a gap of empty chairs between them so the number of empty chairs look the same (varying $\pm1$ seat). The gap number will vary of course

```
132 / 24 = 5 (+12)
133 / 24 = 5 (+13)
134 / 24 = 5 (+14)
```

I'm looking for a way to distribute them and use the modulus to vary the empty seats gap so they look distributed the most along the seats.
**The first and last chairs must be occupied** by two of the $24$ occupants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $132-24 = 108$ empty chairs and $23$ gaps. $108 \equiv 16 \bmod 23$ and $(108-16)/23 = 4$, so you will have 4 or 5 empty chairs in each gap.

The extra-chair gaps can be assigned using a calculation for gap $g$ using $16g \equiv k \bmod 23$, for example if $k<16$ then add a chair to that gap.

---

As a begin-to-end-calculation for $c$ chairs and $p$ people, you would have:
\begin{align}
\text{empty chairs: set }e &= c-p \\[1ex]
\text{#larger gaps: set }n &= (e \bmod p-1) \\[1ex]
\text{then with }i \in \{1..p-1\}\quad g_i &= \frac{e-n}{p-1} + 
\begin{cases} 1 \text{ when }(ni \bmod (p-1)) < n\\
0 \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}\\
\end{align}

with $g_i$ being the number of chairs in gap number $i$.

Comment: Looks good! Can you detail it a little bit more, please? I need to put it in a javascript code.